# Finding Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Calculate the inverse Laplace transform of: $$\frac{1}{s\cdot(\sqrt{s}+1)} \cdot e^{-\sqrt{s} \cdot x}$$

My attempt at the solution was to break down the fraction with partial fraction decomposition as follows: $$\frac{1}{s \cdot (\sqrt{s}+1)} = \frac1s-\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{s}}$$
Then the first part can be easily computed from the table or by using some software: $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}( s^{-1} \cdot e^{-\sqrt{s} \cdot x} )= 1-erf(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}})$$
However the second part is not at all trivial, as I was unable to find any coherent answer to the problem: $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}( (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{s}}) \cdot e^{-\sqrt{s} \cdot x} )$$
Could someone, please, guide towards the correct answer?
I have tried using computer algebra systems such Mathematica, but nothing seems to work.

***Treat x as a constant with x>0.

[image]

Comment: in the first equation, in the exponential what is $x$ in $\sqrt{s}x$?

Comment: I am sorry I have not mentioned that, x is an arbitrary constant such that x>0.

Comment: Using Mathematica I get $\left(t+\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2
   \sqrt{t}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{t} x e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$ (I have to leave right now, sorry. I hope it can help)

Comment: Do you know what the "Convolution Theorem" is?(also use \cdot instead of * for product because * if for convolution)

Comment: Yes, I have tried solving using convolution but the integral seemed to diverge. So, the way I attempted to solve the problem using the convolution was that the Inverse Laplace Transform of a product of two functions is a convolution of the Inverse Laplace Transforms of the two functions. So I have found the inverses for exponential and for the fractions, but when I took the integral, it seemed to diverge.

Comment: @PicaudVincent. It seems you are wrong ?.Check: `FullSimplify[
 LaplaceTransform[(t + x^2/2)*Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - (Sqrt[t]*x)/Sqrt[
     Pi]*Exp[-x^2/(4 t)] // Expand, t, s], 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, s > 0}]` .

Comment: @RenatSergazinov I don't know if the integral diverge but the resulting integral is *extremely hard*

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you are right, my input function was not the good one: conclusion never do something is urgency...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\color{red}{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{\left(1+\sqrt{s}\right) s}\right](t)}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}
   x}}{1+\sqrt{s}}+\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{s}-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{\sqrt{s}}\right](t)=\color{red}{\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2
   \sqrt{t}}\right)-e^{t+x} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 t+x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)}$$
With CAS help:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{s}-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{\sqrt{s}}\right](t)=-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}}}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{t}}+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)$$ 
It's hard to find $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{1+\sqrt{s}}\right](t)$?

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{1+\sqrt{s}}\right](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{L}_a^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}
   x}}{a+\sqrt{s}}\right](q)\right](t)=\mathcal{L}_q\left[\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[e^{-q \sqrt{s}-\sqrt{s}
   x}\right](t)\right](1)=\mathcal{L}_q\left[\frac{e^{-\frac{(q+x)^2}{4 t}} (q+x)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }
   t^{3/2}}\right](1)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}}}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{t}}-e^{t+x} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 t+x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Comment: If I may ask, out of curiosity, how did you come up with such ingenious solution to the second Laplace transform?

Comment: @RenatSergazinov. 
This trick is not mine. A user of https://math.stackexchange.com  used it, but I do not remember which one.